# Reshape data to make stacked barplot with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to make a stacked barplot with in `ggplot2` however I don't have actual labels in the dataset that correspond to categories. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
x <- c("oct", "nov")
oct <- c(2,4)           
nov <- c(5,1)           

qplot(x, oct, geom = "bar", stat = "identity")          
qplot(x, nov, geom = "bar", stat = "identity")
```

Here, I would like to make one barplot in which the first bar stacks (2,4) with different colors and then (5,1) for the second bar with different colors such that 2 and 5 have the same color and 4 and 1 have the same color. Thanks.

Comment: Try this `ggplot(reshape2::melt(data.frame(x, oct, nov), id.vars="x"), 
aes(x, value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`.

Comment: Great thanks; if you put this as the answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
library(reshape2)
df <- melt(data.frame(x, oct, nov), id.vars="x")
ggplot(df, aes(x, value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```